# Anyone managed to upgrade to EE 1.13 and keep the old urls in place?

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13, enterprise-1.13

we tried an upgrade to 1.13.1.x for an existing site. One of the requirements is to keep the old urls or at least do 301 redirects to the new ones. The site has duplicate category url keys in different parts of the tree (a/foo and b/foo) and multiple websites, so some categories have the same name under different domains (i.e. domain1.com/foo and domain2.com/bar). While this worked fine for previous versions, it looks like now the category url keys need to be unique. Even with the latest patches provided by Magento, the url keys still get numbers attached to them and lose the parent path, a/foo becoming foo and b/foo becoming foo-1. For the default store view, the old urls still work if accessed directly, but for the other stores they throw 404s.

I know that since this is about EE support is the best place to go and we did that, but I was wondering if anyone else stumbled upon this and got it working or at least got some insights on a possible fix.

Comment: Check out my reply to another user who too had issues with URLs in Magento here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5566/488 We to updated to 1.13 and had the same issue as you. The script I included can be tweaked to fix catalog URL issues as well. Either way, we have successfully upgraded to 1.13 and got past the duplicate url key issue with both products and categories so that post might help you too.

Comment: @ОлегС. Please post your comment as an answer.